# AngularJS data-ng-repeat does not show any changes when Array was modified

Tags: angularjs

Okay, so I have this custom directive that is responsible for showing Notes for a product that users have left.

```
<mx-note-manager-two isModalPopup="true" is-show-date-range="{{IsShowNoteDateRangeControl}}" recordType="BOM_Header" recordId="{{UniqKey}}" note-save-success-call="CheckItemLevelData" noteLabel={{translation.BOMNote}} record="{{SummaryGridPartNumber}}"></mx-note-manager-two>
```

That directive inside of it has this div, responsible for showing all the note located in the $scope.MessageList

```
<div data-ng-repeat="message in MessageList" ng-class="!$first ? 'padding-top2px padding-left2px' :''">
... <!-- some divs to show data in message -->
</div>
```

So whenever we open a page that contains this directive, it calls the controller that sends an API, then the response it gets assigns to the $scope.MessageList

```
MXNoteService.getMxTwoNotes('api/MXNote/GetMxTwoNotes', { params: { recordType: $scope.RecordType, recordId: $scope.RecordId, NoteCategory: 2 } }).then(function (responseData) {
...
$scope.MessageList = responseData.data.responseObject[0].ListOfNotes
...
if ($scope.IsFocus) {
setTimeout(function () {
$('#note-text-area').focus();
$scope.$apply();
}, 0);
}
...
}
```

And the directive itself

```
directive('mxNoteManagerTwo', function ($rootScope, MXNoteService) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: function (element, attributes) {
                if (!$rootScope.IsNullOrUndefined(attributes.ismodalpopup) && attributes.ismodalpopup === 'true') {
                    return 'SinglePageApp/GenericControls/MXNoteManager/MXNote2Model.html';
                } else {
                    return 'SinglePageApp/GenericControls/MXNoteManager/MXNote2.html';
                }
            },
            scope: {
                recordType: '@',
                recordId: '@',
                isEdit: '@',
                isShowDateRange: '@',
                isShowHeader: '@',
                isEditDisable: '@',
                isShowAttachment: '@',
                isAddAttachment: '@',
                record: '@',
                keyValue: '@',
                isShowCamera: '@',
                isFocus: '@'
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                //here we assign attributes
                //...
                MXNoteService.setValues = function (record, recordId, title, moduleName, isEdit) {
                    scope.Record = record;
                    scope.RecordId = recordId;
                    scope.NoteLabel = title ? title : scope.NoteLabel;
                    scope.RecordType = moduleName ? moduleName : scope.RecordType;
                    scope.IsEdit = !$rootScope.IsNullOrUndefined(isEdit) ? isEdit : scope.IsEdit;
                    scope.GetMxTwoNotes(scope.RecordType, scope.RecordId);
                }
                setTimeout(function () {
                    scope.GetMxTwoNotes();
                }, 500);
            },
            controller: 'MXNote2Controller',
        }
```

After we do any changes to the $scope.MessageList like deleting all the data then overriding it with a new one, the changes do not appear in the page. Even after the $scope.$apply() was called.

I've tried multiple solutions from StackOverflow, like adding $timeout, using angular.Extend, calling the digest cycle multiple times after each time $scope.MessageList was changed.

Answer (score 0):

Your design seems like it might be getting in the way.  First you're using a lot of interpolation when binding would be more appropriate.  What you're encountering would be typical of attribute binding.  Here is roughly what I'd expect:

```
<mx-note-manager-two isModalPopup="true" 
    is-show-date-range="IsShowNoteDateRangeControl" 
    recordType="BOM_Header" 
    recordId="UniqKey" 
    note-save-success-call="CheckItemLevelData"
    noteLabel="translation.BOMNote" 
    record="SummaryGridPartNumber"></mx-note-manager-two>
```

To get your directive to respond accordingly you'd want to define the scope like so:

```
            scope: {
                recordType: '@',
                recordId: '=',
                isEdit: '@',
                isShowDateRange: '=',
                isShowHeader: '@',
                isEditDisable: '@',
                isShowAttachment: '@',
                isAddAttachment: '@',
                record: '=',
                keyValue: '@',
                isShowCamera: '@',
                isFocus: '@',
                noteSaveSuccessCall: '&',  // notice this was an attribute that seemed to be a callback so use the & binding for that.                
            },
```

I left some '@' bindings for what appear to be constants, but you'll have to make the determination if that's appropriate.  It's fine to use '@' binding when you think an attribute will take on static values (ie not from variables).

Anywhere you feel like you need to use interpolation (ie `{{ someValue }}`) I'd use `=`.  If you did that then you probably don't need `MXNodesService.setValues` anymore because if those values changed they would be updated by binding into the directive.

If you need to respond to changes and reload `GetMxTwoNotes` then you can use a `$watch`.  Like so:

```
   scope.$watch('recordId', (oldValue,newValue) => {
      if( oldValue !== newValue ) {
         scope.GetMxTwoNotes();
      }
   });
```

Something else to consider is if you have several fields that are dependent like you can't call `GetMxTwoNotes()` when `recordId` changes because you also need `recordType` or some other field.  Then don't split those up as separate attributes when binding.  Have a single object that has those values and pass that into the scope.  That way when that object changes you have all dependent fields needed, and can execute it immediately in the watch function.  Another reason to not use '@' attribute binding and to use '=' binding because you can pass regular javascript objects as properties to the directive.  For example:

```
<mx-note-manager-two is-modal-popup="true" note-params="params"></mx-note-manager-two>
```

Where `params` would be an object like so:

```
params = {
   recordId: 5,
   recordType: '...',
   NoteLabel: '...',
   ...
}
```

I'd also consider removing the use of timeout and just make the call in the link function.  You shouldn't need to delay loading, and doing it in a timeout function means it's out of the digest cycle.  I know you had mentioned using $timeout which would retain the digest cycle (ie no need to call $apply), but you need to simplify things so you aren't fighting angularjs.

Without seeing MXNote2Controller it's hard to say what else could be contributing the your Message updates not being seen.